# Parse JSON string to Model Object type Array

Tags: swift3

I got Encrypted data from API hit by below method

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!)
```

converted data into JSON but still it is encrypted

```
var json = try(JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments))
```

converted it into string

```
let arr:String = json as! String
```

decrypted it

```
let jsonText = arr.fromBase64()//extension method, given end of question
```

now it is in Json Formate as below (this is only 1 record, there are more than 1 records in Json string)

```
{
  "CompanyAlt_Key": 1,
  "Company_Name": "XYZ LTD",
  "TableName": "CompanyList"
},
```

I have a model of same type

```
public class CompanyList {
    public var companyAlt_Key : Int?
    public var company_Name : String?
    public var tableName : String?
}
```

here is fromBase64 method

```
func fromBase64() -> String {
    let data = NSData.init(base64Encoded: self, options: []) ?? NSData()
    return String(data: data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? ""
}
```

I am facing problem to get the Json String into an array of type CompanyList class

Help would be appreciate

Comment: It does not seem you have encrypted data, just encoded. The main difference is that encrypted data requires a key to decrypt and encoded data does not. Examples of encryption include AES, RSA and EC while examples of encoding include hexadecimal, URL encoding, ASCII, UTF-8 and Base64.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert your `jsonString` to data first:

```
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
```

The convert the data to an array

```
let array = JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: nil) as? [[String: Any]]
```

Then iterate through the array…

```
let companies = array?.map {
    return CompanyList(dictionary: $0)
}
```

Implement an `init` method for your `CompanyList`, passing in a dictionary for each record in your response…

```
public class CompanyList {
    public var companyAlt_Key : Int?
    public var company_Name : String?
    public var tableName : String?

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {        
        companyAlt_Key = dictionary["companyAlt_Key"] as? Int
        company_Name = dictionary["company_Name"] as? String
        tableName = dictionary["tableName"] as? String
    }
}
```

You can also use this to validate the data. If the fields in your class are non-optional, you can use an optional `init` as follows…

```
public class CompanyList {
    public var companyAlt_Key : Int
    public var company_Name : String
    public var tableName : String

    init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {        
        guard let companyAlt_Key = dictionary["companyAlt_Key"] as? Int,
        let company_Name = dictionary["company_Name"] as? String,
        let tableName = dictionary["tableName"] as? String else {
            return nil 
        }

        self.companyAlt_Key = companyAlt_Key
        self.company_Name = company_Name
        self.tableName = tableName
    }
}
```

If you're using an optional init, use `flatMap` to ensure you don't have any optional elements in your array…

```
let companies = array?.flatMap {
    return CompanyList(dictionary: $0)
}
```

Comment: your code is running without error, but how to append object of type CompanyList into an Array of CompanyList. in this method let companies = array?.map {
    return CompanyList(dictionary: $0)
} , it returns,

Comment: let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: []) as? [[String: Any]]
array is also nil,

Comment: To append to an existing array: `myArray.append(contentsOf: otherArray)`.

Comment: If you just try `let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: [])` is array nil? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: it doesn't throw any error but it shows nil on debugger